# I can't get the text in the google quick answers field in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Making a python voice assistant that should parse the google site and speak the text . But nothing works for me, I get "None" or an error in the output. Here is my code:

```
g = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
text= "когда родился сталин"
url = "https://www.google.com/search/?text=" + text + "&hl=en"

request_result = requests.get( url, headers=g ) 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup( request_result.text , 'lxml' ) 
gogl = soup.select_one('.t2b5Cf').text

print(gogl)
```

I tried using the  command soup .find still didn't help
please help I will be grateful

Comment: Try changing .t2b5Cf to .LXD9yf  in your soup.select_one

Comment: Those class names are generated dynamically and might change regularly.  You may need to use a different mechanism to find your result.

Comment: hello, I changed to .LXD9yf nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

Try to set right cookies + headers:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

g = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

params = {"q": "когда родился сталин", "hl": "en"}
url = "https://www.google.com/search"

cookies = {"CONSENT": "YES+cb.20220419-08-p0.cs+FX+111"}

request_result = requests.get(url, headers=g, params=params, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request_result.text, "lxml")
```

Prints:

```
Gori, Georgia
```